# Determine the thin SVD of A= [1,1]^T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I have been tasked to find a thin singular value decomposition of the transpose of matrix A= [1,1]. 
I am not able to find how to find an SVD of a single column matrix either in my textbook, notes or online.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am completely lost.

Comment: Do you know how to find the SVD of a rectangular matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find a unit vector $\mathbf u$, a nonnegative number $s$ and a scalar $v$ of modulus 1 such that $\pmatrix{1\\ 1}=\mathbf u s v$. This is by no means a difficult problem.

Comment: I think I am overthinking the problem but hope I have arrived at the correct answer. I am getting [1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)]*sqrt(2)*1

Comment: @k.math2 That's correct. It's as simple as that.